# Drop down selection to people/group picker

Tags: infopath, dropdown, infopath-data-connections

I have a question

I have infopath form and i have two fields that i need to connect.

What i did is i created a list containing the APPROVERS, REGION and EMAIL ADDRESS. this list has a lookup.

I have field named: REGION (this is also a drop down selection)
I have also field named: APPROVERS (this is also a drop down selection)
I have also field named: EMAIL ADDRESS (this is a person/group selection)

The process flow is when i select the REGION the assigned approver will appear in the APPROVERS.  I already do this. My problem is when i select the APPROVERS i want that their EMAIL ADDRESS autonatically appear in ths EMAIL ADDRESS field.

Is it possible? Or do you have any suggestion on how i am going to achieve what i want?
Or do you have better idea.
Please kindly support.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to load email addresses when a name is selected in the field. It will not happen automatically. You will have load the email addresses from userprofile service in InfoPath through a data connection. but if your goal is to send an email to the Email address field then your workflow should send email to a user name in the field.